# Why ASP.NET TextBox.Text only returns 250 character?

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net Form page I have a TextBox control like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuestion" runat="server" MaxLength="1000" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="99%" Height="50px"></asp:TextBox>
```

when i type a long sentence (250+ characters) and submit the form in the code behind page I only get 250 character when I user this

```
txtQuestion.Text
```

However, when I use this

```
Request[txtQuestion.UniqueID]
```

I get the whole sentence.

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. Can anyone help me out here?

### EDIT

I have tried the suggestion made by **Ramesh Rajendran** by doing the following -

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuestion" runat="server" Rows="50" CssClass="queCss" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

The Css class is defined as follows -

```
.queCss
{
    width:99%;
    height:50px;
}
```

I would also like to mention that I am using JQuery AJAX and Page Methods to populate data on some ListBox. So I have set `EnableEventValidation` to `false`. I am also using JQuery to populate some dynamic textboxes whose values I read after PostBack using Request Object.

Comment: Are you doing anything out of the ordinary? Like is this on Mono instead of IIS, or are you using any funky controls or handlers which might screw with your controls? Because I don't see how this could happen in a regular app. Try recreating in an empty project and see if you get the same results - I don't.

Comment: Your code is working to me !!

Comment: Even if I remove `MaxLength` the problem persists.

Comment: Remove this line Request[txtQuestion.UniqueID]

Answer (score 0):

The max length only for using in validate  textbox  characters .

You can use `TextMode="MultiLine"` and `Rows="50"`  in your textbox

Please use this below textbox instead of your textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuestion" runat="server" Rows="50" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Edit**

Remove this line

```
Request[txtQuestion.UniqueID]
```

then check it

Comment: I'll check it out and let you know.